# In need of a way to mass configure Android kiosk apps during install

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have recently written a kiosk application for Android and I now need to deploy on a large number of tablets.

I have already started writing a ShellScripts in Linux to push the required directories and content to the sdcard as well as install the apk.

However due to the nature of this app there are a lot of preference settings which control the layout and theme of the kiosk user interface.

So my question is how should I go about automatically configuring these settings during install time? Please note that one batch of tablets may be configured differently than another batch.

Would it be best to restructure the app so as to import/load settings from a file which my shellscript places on the sd card?
What I was really hoping is there are ways of doing this through ADB or by other means (possibly a method of accessing and modifying sharedprefs externally).

Also I'm now convinced that without rooting I will not be able to just simply copy and replace the sharedprefs file

I'm relatively new to Android and ADB. But I'm very open to all suggestions and recommendations. Believe me I do not look forward to having to change the settings in a few hundred tablets by hand!!

[edit]

According to "[How to view SharedPreferences xml file without root access](http://dx3.psychopyko.com/2014/03/08/how-to-view-sharedpreferences-xml-file-without-root-access/)" they state that using the "run-as" command and specifying a package name will allow access to sharedprefs. 
But only if the app is debuggable.
Which doesn't sound good for production.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the system settings through ADB and modify them, however you're right about needing to be root.

Enter the device through adb, access the device's shell, and read the database with sqlite3
`sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`

Then modify the values you feel need changing. There are other roots, such as custom ROMs but they require more work and might be more time consuming.
You may need to reboot the device for the changes to take effect.

[image: settings.db open with sqlitebrowser]